# How to know list of service impacted by Microsoft CU Updates

Tags: sharepoint-server

Is there any way to know list of Windows & Farm Services will get impacted while installing any CU Updates on SharePoint 2019 Servers? e.g. We are installing [Feb'22 CU updates](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/topic/description-of-the-security-update-for-sharepoint-server-2019-february-8-2022-kb5002135-5cfc06d2-e79a-4ec3-af02-59b5be9b6abf). But, would like to know which Windows or Farm Service will get impacted.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not entirely sure what you're after, do you mean which Windows services will be restarted during installation of a CU? When you install a Cumulative Update on SharePoint Server, it is common best practice to restart the servers in the farm. Usually once before installing the binaries, and once after. Considering that, all Windows services will be affected.

On the other hand, if you have a redundant setup and use Zero Downtime Patching, your restarts will not affect end users, but that was not your question. :)

Let me know if this was what you're after or if it is something else.

Below are my favorite links on the subject:

SharePoint Patching Best Practices
https://blog.stefan-gossner.com/2020/02/11/sharepoint-patching-best-practices/

SharePoint Server 2016/2019 Zero-Downtime Patching demystified
https://blog.stefan-gossner.com/2016/04/29/sharepoint-2016-zero-downtime-patching-demystified/

Video demo of Zero Downtime Patching in SharePoint Server 2016
https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/upgrade-and-update/video-demo-of-zero-downtime-patching-in-sharepoint-server-2016